# Android Studio: Passing multiple values using intent PROVIDES ONLY 1 VALUE?

Tags: java, android-intent, android-studio, android-bundle

I am trying to make a quiz where users choose an answer in each activity, and the final page provides an answer based on the chosen options. Therefore, I want to pass these values to the final activity, but only the last chosen value seems to show.

First Activity:

```
public class Quiz extends Activity {

Button btn;
RadioGroup rg;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    rg= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an answer",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quiz1.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
            bundle.putString("rg", radioButton.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);

        }

        }

    });
  }
}
```

Second Activity:

```
public class Quiz1 extends Activity {

Button btn;
RadioGroup rg1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz1);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn1);
    rg1= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an answer",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quiz2.class);
                Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
                int id = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                bundle1.putString("rg1", radioButton.getText().toString());
                intent1.putExtras(bundle1);
                startActivity(intent1);

            }

        }

    });
  }
}
```

Now this follows for a total of 7 activities.. not including the final activity 
Here is the 7ths (called Quiz6) activity:

```
public class Quiz6 extends Activity {

Button btn;
RadioGroup rg6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz6);


    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn6);
    rg6= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg6);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rg6.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an answer",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                Intent intent6 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Final1.class);
                Bundle bundle6 = new Bundle();
                int id = rg6.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                bundle6.putString("rg6", radioButton.getText().toString());
                intent6.putExtras(bundle6);
                startActivity(intent6);

            }

        }

    });
  }
}
```

You get the idea :)

Here is the FINAL activity (called Final1) here the results are show

here is the code

```
public class Final1 extends Activity {

Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.final1);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg"));

    Bundle bundle1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    textView.setText(bundle1.getCharSequence("rg1"));

    Bundle bundle2 = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    textView.setText(bundle2.getCharSequence("rg2"));

    Bundle bundle3 = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    textView.setText(bundle3.getCharSequence("rg3"));

    Bundle bundle4 = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    textView.setText(bundle4.getCharSequence("rg4"));

    Bundle bundle5 = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt5);
    textView.setText(bundle5.getCharSequence("rg5"));

    Bundle bundle6 = getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView textView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt6);
    textView.setText(bundle6.getCharSequence("rg6"));

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.restartBtn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), Quiz.class);
            startActivityForResult(in, 0);
        }
    });

  }

}
```

What ends up happening once I run the program is that only "textView" ends up changing to the chosen choice on the activity right before the final activity, shown above

Any help is appreciated, thanks lots <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An activity's intent only has one `Bundle` associated with it. Thus, you are only passing the last bundle to your final activity, the others are passed to the immediately following activity instead. You can fix this issue by doing

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras(); //this gets the current activity's extras
RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
bundle.putString("rg1", radioButton.getText().toString());
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of creating a new bundle each time as you do now. then pass this bundle along to the following activity. That way, each time you get a new answer, you are adding it to your bundle of answers, rather than creating a new bundle with only one item each time.

Then in your final activity, you only have to get the one bundle, and can pull all the answers out of it. NOTE: You'll want to make sure that your'e updating the correct textview with the correct text. In your question, `textView` is the only view that gets updated, 6 times, and the others do not get updated at all.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg"));

TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
textView1.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg1"));

TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
textView2.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg2"));

TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3);
textView3.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg3"));

TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt4);
textView4.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg4"));

TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt5);
textView5.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg5"));

TextView textView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt6);
textView6.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg6"));
```

Comment: But in my first activity (Quiz) would i not have to first do `Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();`?. And also would I actually have to specifically pass and receive it after each activity or can i just do it all at once at the final activity? because I don't know what you meant by receive it in the next activity, I'm not sure how to exactly do that :$ sorry I'm a noob. Thank you

Comment: You're correct, in the first activity, you would want a new `Bundle`. After that, you'll be grabbing the bundle you passed into the current activity, adding a value to it, and passing the same bundle on to the next activity. This way, when you come to the end, the bundle has everything you added across activities.

Comment: Oh I see :) but would I also have to add a code in order for it to receive it in the next activity or will it automatically do so by doing `Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();` , because I'm still getting only the last value at the end

Comment: That's the nice thing about this approach. Android does that for you! It saves the intent when the activity receives it, and you can access it at any time with `getIntent()`.

Comment: so now i have `} else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quiz6.class);
                   // Bundle bundle5 = new Bundle();
                    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                    int id = rg5.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                    bundle.putString("rg5", radioButton.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);` and in first activity I have `Bundle bundle = new Bundle();` instead of the getIntent, still same issue tho :(

Comment: Take a look at the edits I made. Specifically, make sure that the right text is getting set to the right text views.