# Android Studio: Passing multiple values through multiple activities ONLY SHOWS ONE? :(

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-studio, android-bundle

Hello :) so here is how my "app" is supposed to work. There are multiple activities, and in each activity, there is a question, which has answers that can be chosen with `radiobuttons`. It eventually gets to the final activity where a result is shown.

Here is my code for the first activity

```
`public class Quiz extends Activity {
    Button btn;
    RadioGroup rg;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz);

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an answer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quiz1.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                    bundle.putString("rg", radioButton.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }

        });
      }
    }
```

Second activity:

```
public class Quiz1 extends Activity {

Button btn;
RadioGroup rg1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.quiz1);

    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn1);
    rg1= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an answer",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quiz2.class);
                Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                int id = rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                bundle.putString("rg1", radioButton.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

        }

    });
  }
}
```

And third:

```
public class Quiz2 extends Activity {

    Button btn;
    RadioGroup rg2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.quiz2);


        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBtn2);
        rg2= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg2);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select an answer",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Quiz3.class);
                    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
                    int id = rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(id);
                    bundle.putString("rg2", radioButton.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }

            }

        });
      }
    }
```

This trend continues for 7 activities

Here is the final code:

```
public class Final1 extends Activity {

Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.final1);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg"));

    TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg1"));

    TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt2);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg2"));

    TextView textView3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt3);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg3"));

    TextView textView4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt4);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg4"));

    TextView textView5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt5);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg5"));

    TextView textView6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt6);
    textView.setText(bundle.getCharSequence("rg6"));

    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.restartBtn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), Quiz.class);
            startActivityForResult(in, 0);
        }
    });

  }
}
```

This is what I get in my final page once I run the app, 
textViews display text set to the option chosen right before the FINAL results page...
the rest of the textViews (so textView1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) are all empty

Any help is appreciated, thank you <3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio: Passing multiple values using intent PROVIDES ONLY 1 VALUE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644942/android-studio-passing-multiple-values-using-intent-provides-only-1-value)

Answer (score 0):

For your case, best way to save and retrieve data is using `Sharedpreferences.`

In all of your activites initialise sharedpreferences as

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myprefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And instead of saving in bundle, save as

```
prefs.edit.putString("rg2", radioButton.getText().toString()).apply();
```

and then, in your final activity retrieve as

```
prefs.getString("rg2","");
```

If you want to do it using Intents, you have to pass old data to new activity in each activity.
So, in your second class,

```
intent.putExtras("rg",bundle.getString("rg")); );
intent.putExtras("rg1", radioButton.getText().toString());
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Use **Sharedpreferences** instead.

Make below class and use it when needed.

```
    public class PreferenceManager {
    private static final String PREFERENCES_QUIZ_ANS = "quiz_ans";
    private static final String QUIZ_ANS_1 = "quiz_ans_1";

    private static SharedPreferences getQuizAnsPreferences(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_QUIZ_ANS, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void storeQuizAns_1(Context context, String quiz_ans_1){
        getServicePreferences(context).edit().putString(QUIZ_ANS_1, quiz_ans_1).commit();
    }

    public static String getQuizAns_1(Context context){
        return getServicePreferences(context).getString(QUIZ_ANS_1, null);
    }
}
```

Use it like below in every activity to store the answer.

```
PreferenceManager.storeQuizAns_1(getApplicationContext(), radioButton.getText().toString());
```

Use it like below in FINAL activity to get the answer and print to the **TEXTVIEW**.

`TextView textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt1);
textView1.setText(PreferenceManager.getQuizAns_1(this));`

You have to make methods like storeQuizAns_1 and getQuizAns_1 as much as questions you have.
You have to make constants like QUIZ_ANS_1 as much as questions you have.